# Mouse right click for keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

I need when I click on `Mouse Right-Click`

do the same effect like I clicked on keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

It will be temporarily event, I hope no restart or any complex settings.

Comment: Check if your mouse Driver supports Macros. That would be the "easy, no restart" option if you have a gaming mouse (with the appropriate drivers and software) for example. I suspect AutoHotKey might be an option too. If you specify your particular mouse, maybe someone can tell you if and how to.

Comment: @TheUser1024 Logitech M345

Comment: Windows already has a keyboard shortcut for this: `Shift` + `F10`.

Comment: @TheUser1024 I think SetPoint™ Software - Logitech will do what I want for my mouse, thanks to you I reached to this solution

Comment: @Jim: You're welcome, i guessed all you needed was a bit of pointing in the right direction. have fun and a good one ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [X-mouse Button Control](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm) to create a macro on your right mouse button.

Comment: Thanks :), also this will do the same: http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html . any way I will use SetPoint Logitech Software for my mouse, but if I need to do this with another mouse your answer is the right solution

Answer (score 2):

Simple. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> should work for this or you can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/).

Code:

```
; Move to specified coordinates then right-click once:
MouseClick, right, 450, 300
```

Comment: I dont need the context menu, I want the Right-click do other event, thank you :)

Comment: @Jim See the answer now..